# "login" and "sign up" web services are not giving required json output in swift using alamofire

Tags: json, swift, api, web-services, alamofire

1)

I am new in using alamofire.Here is my attempt to use alamofire to make web service check where i am wrong .I Have made a login webservice in the `loginviewcontroller.swift` as follows

```
let url="http://192.169.201.32:9000//users/authenticate"
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters:["username":"andrews","password":"admin2"], encoding: URLEncoding.default)
            .responseJSON { response in
                print("abcsign in")
                print(response)
                 print("abcsign in3")
                print(response.result)
                //to get status code
                if let status = response.response?.statusCode {
                    switch(status){
                    case 201:
                        print("example success")
                    default:
                        print("error with response status: \(status)")
                    }
                }
                //to get JSON return value
                if let result = response.result.value {
                    let JSON = result as! NSDictionary
                     print("abcsign in 2")
                    print(JSON)

                }

        }
```

print(response)

**FAILURE**

> responseSerializationFailed(Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.jsonSerializationFailed(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 2." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 2.}))

```
print(response.result)
```

**FAILURE**

> error with response status: 404

2)

The second `signUpviewcontroller.swift`  is connected with the `signUp` view controller .In `signUpViewController.swift` the code for singUp webservice is as follow

```
  let url="http://192.169.201.32:9000//patient/signUp"

    @IBAction func signUpButtonWasPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters:["dob":DateOfBirthTextFeild.text ,
                                                          "email":emailIdTextField.text ,
                                                          "firstName":FirstNameTextField.text ,
                                                          "gender":genderTextField.text ,
                                                          "lastName":LastNameTextField.text ,
                                                          "middleName":MiddleNameTextField.text ,
                                                          "password":passwordTextField.text ,    //password must be 8 char long 
                                                          "ssn":ssnTextField.text], encoding: URLEncoding.default)
            .responseJSON { response in
                print("abcsig up in")
                print(response)
                print("abcsign up in3")
                print(response.result)
                //to get status code
                if let status = response.response?.statusCode {
                    switch(status){
                    case 201:
                        print("example success")
                    default:
                        print("error with response status: \(status)")
                    }
                }
                //to get JSON return value
                if let result = response.result.value {
                    let JSON = result as! NSDictionary
                    print("abcsign up in 2")
                    print(JSON)

                }

        }
    }
```

print(response) out put is

**FAILURE**

> responseSerializationFailed(Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.jsonSerializationFailed(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 2." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 2.}))

```
print(response.result)
```

> error with response status: 404

how can I get the valid json response ?

you can download the project from this links .https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WjEng8RtRcuPOccTUHchDELIE1JSYlNW/view?usp=sharing
Here on postman the api is showing the required json out put .
[image]

provide the parameters in body. You can add the json parameters converting the json url request to post .In below tab select body put the parameters here  by selecting the raw.
[image]

[image]

Comment: 404 means that the web service not available, check that web service application is running

Comment: these webservice are giving valid response on postman

Comment: I would suggest comparing URL and data you send to the server

Comment: i think you are sending parameters as url encoding , this might causing an error , try sending the data in body instead.

Comment: how to stop sending parameters as url encoder and send the parameters in body ?

Comment: "http://192.169.201.32:9000//patient/signUp" There are two slashes after 9000, could this be the cause of the 404?

Comment: see the post man response for this url it is showing the desired out put

Comment: encoding should be jsonencoding.default

Comment: Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters:["username":"andrews","password":"admin2"], encoding:  jsonencoding.default)......./////Error Use of unresolved identifier 'jsonencoding

Comment: still json output is not valid

Comment: did you checked with raw mode, preview mode..?,is it valid json. some time postman shows the artificial intelligences why because you already mentioned header as content type json. please check in the rest of mode by that you can get clear, issue is from server side or client side

Comment: i have attached 2nd image in question ..."provide the parameter in postman body like shown in image

Answer (score 0):

I have tested same with the postman, see the below-attached images. Maybe it is problem with validating URL or from the backed development. SO please provide the more information to give you the correct answer.

[image]
[image]

Comment: i have attached 2nd image in question ..."provide the parameter in   postman body like shown in image

Comment: in Postman provide the parameters in body. You can add the json parameters converting the json url request to post .In below tab select body put the parameters here by selecting the raw.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use json encoding instead of url encoding? I noticed that in postman you sent the request with raw data as body and use `application/json`.

Try to change the Alamofire's request method like this:

```
Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters:["username":"andrews","password":"admin2"], encoding: JSONEncoding.default) // instead of URLEncoding.default
```